# ng-template not displaying views in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I was learning about AngularJS views from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm). The example which the site has shown is supposed to output this:

[image: output]

However, the [output](//jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/xtzofcqL/embedded/result/) is not showing in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/xtzofcqL/):

```js
         var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
         mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            
            when('/addStudent', {
               templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
               controller: 'AddStudentController'
            }).
            
            when('/viewStudents', {
               templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
               controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
            }).
            
            otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/addStudent'
            });
         }]);
         
         mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
         });
         
         mainApp.controller('ViewStudentsController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This page will be used to display all the students";
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>AngularJS <a href='http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm'>ng-template example</a></h2>
      <div ng-app = "mainApp">
         <p><a href = "#addStudent">Add Student</a></p>
         <p><a href = "#viewStudents">View Students</a></p>
         <div ng-view></div>
         
         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "addStudent.htm">
            <h2> Add Student </h2>
            {{message}}
         </script>
         
         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "viewStudents.htm">
            <h2> View Students </h2>
            {{message}}
         </script>
      </div>
```

I believe, I have selected **LOAD TYPE** correctly:

[image: LOAD TYPE]

> What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @PankajParkar In the [fiddle which you referenced](https://jsfiddle.net/xtzofcqL/2/), the output is not showing up :) +3 for your for your advice.

Comment: Actually I forget to update the fiddle.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get ngRoute working you have to add :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

The problem was caused by missing inclusion of ngRoute module

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/xtzofcqL/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong `href`s, those should have `/` before them. Also you haven't added `angular-route.js` in your Fiddle.

**Markup**

```
<p><a href = "#/addStudent">Add Student</a></p>
<p><a href = "#/viewStudents">View Students</a></p>
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pankajparkar/od3qcm33/)